# Compare local list to DataBase

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a local List with entities, some hundreds, and I have a SQL Server table where I store the ID of the successful processed entities, some millions. I would like to know, which entities form my local set are not yet processed i.e. are not in the SQL Table.

The first approach is to iterate through the local list with the following Linq statement:

```
Entity entity = db.Entities.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID ==  ID);
if (entity == null)   { NewList.Add(ID) }
```

the `NewList` would then contain all the new entities. However this is very slow.

In LINQ, how would you send the entire local list to the SQL Server with one call and then return the ones not in the SQL table?

Do you really have to create a temporary table with my local list, then left-join on the already processed table and return the ones with a null?

Comment: Are you able to check the row of the record. Let's say if you query ur ID and it doesnt exist then the database will return 0 number of rows. From there, you will be able to add a new record

Comment: The above LINQ statement does this. But it generates a query for every entity in my local list, that's making it slow.

Comment: Use `Contains`. By the way, there's no local list in your code, which is too sketchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.Contains` method to retrieve already processed ids
and `Except` to create list of not yet processed ids.

```
var localList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

var processed = db.Entities
    .Where(entity => localList.Contains(entity.Id))
    .Select(entity => entity.Id)
    .ToList();

var notProcessed = localList.Except(processed).ToList();
```

It will depend on provider, but `.Contains` should generate sql like:

```
SELECT Id FROM Entity WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

suggestion:

create a temp table and insert your IDs

select your result on the SQL side

EDIT:

"Can you do that in LINQ?"

TL;DR:

yes* but that's an ugly piece of work, write the SQL yourself

*)depends on what you mean with "in" LINQ, because that is not in the scope of LINQ. In other words: a LINQ expression is one layer too abstract, but if you happen to have an LINQ accessible implementation for this, you can *use* this in your LINQ statements

on the LINQ expression side you have something like:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };
List<int> result = someQueryable.Where(x=>lst.Contains(x.ID)).Select(x=>x.ID).ToList();
```

the question now is: what happens on the SQL side (assuming the queryable leads us to a SQL database)?

the queryable provider (e.g. Entity Framework) somehow has to translate that into SQL, execute it and come back with the result

here would be the place to modify the translation...

for example examine the expression tree with regard to the object that is the target for the Contains(...) call and if it is more than just a few elements, go for the temp table approach...

the very same LINQ expression can be translated into different SQL commands. The provider decides how the translation has to be done.

if your provider lacks support for large Contains(...) cases, you will probably experience poor performance... good thing is usually nobody forces you to use it this way ... you can skip linq for performance optimized queries, or you could write a provider extension yourself but then you are not on the "doing something with LINQ"-side but extending the functionality of your LINQ provider

if you are not developing a large scalable product that will be deployed to work with different DB-Backends, it is usually not worth the effort... the easier way to go is to write the sql yourself and just use the raw sql option of your db connection

Comment: Can you do that in LINQ?